# Printing form created in javafx

Tags: javafx

I am doing a project in javafx in which we create forms ( forms like admission form etc)
Form contains many labels,textfields (filled with data from database) and some images.
I want to print these labels, data from textfields and the images in the same layout in which they were created ( I mean, after printing textfield1 should not be in front of label2 etc).
Is is possible? or is it possible to convert this form to pdf file so that it could be printed later?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to take a snapshot of the Scene:

```
Scene scene;
WritableImage image = scene.snapshot(null);
```

And then you can save this image in an image format:

http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/2012/12/save-writableimage-to-file.html